# jsf conditionally set id

Tags: jsf, parameters, custom-tag

i have a custom tag and want to allow to set the id of an inner element

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">

<f:subview rendered="#{not empty id}">
    <h:message styleClass="message" id="#{id}" errorClass="message error"
        warnClass="message warn" for="#{element}" />
</f:subview>
<f:subview rendered="#{not id}">
    <h:message styleClass="message" errorClass="message error"
        warnClass="message warn" for="#{element}" />
</f:subview>
</html>
```

but i always get

```
Empty id attribute is not allowed
```

how can i archieve that when the user sets an id it is used, and when not jsf should generate it by its own

Answer (score 1):

Use `<c:if>` to conditionally add a `<f:attribute>` with the `id`.

```
<h:message styleClass="message" errorClass="message error" warnClass="message warn" for="#{element}">
    <c:if test="#{not empty id}">
        <f:attribute name="id" value="#{id}" />
    </c:if>
</h:message>
```

By the way, using `<html>` instead of `<ui:composition>` in a custom tag or even without it is quite strange. Are you sure that you end up with syntactically valid HTML? Further, your second `<f:subview rendered>` expression is incorrect, but that has nothing to do with the particular error message you got.

Answer (score 0):

Using [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)'s answer left me with `IllegalArgumentException` in `UIComponent` class where it's specifically thrown for `id`:

```
else if ("id".equals(name) || "parent".equals(name)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

I ended up using Omnifaces' `o:tagAttribute`.

Comment: How did you use the `o:tagAttribute`? If I place it as first element in the composition, then add `id="#{id}"` to the element I want it to use I get the same error of empty id not allowed if id is not explicitly set. If I place it instead of the `<f:attribute>` inside of the element I want to use it, it does nothing.